# Why are some roads blocked off?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

While driving I've noticed that there are many roads in the game world that are blocked off by floating stop signs. The roads also don't show up on the GPS. For example (click for larger versions):

[image]

Another variety:

[image]

Those barriers are completely impassable for the player, but not for AI cars:

[image]

What is the purpose of these barriers and the inaccessible roads? Will they open up later in the game, or perhaps in a future patch? Are they just places for the AI cars to spawn/despawn without the player seeing?

Comment: "Because the devs wanted to do that" - I guess they didn't create an infinite number of roads, and therefore for aesthetic purposes they chose to add road entrances but block them off. Whether or not these additional routes will be added as later DLC only the developers know...

Comment: @kalina If the devs didn't want to make a lot of roads, it would have been easier to not make a lot of roads, rather than to make a lot of roads but block some of them off. Though I suppose it can help make the game world look bigger and more detailed than it actually is. Would be nice to know for sure, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The road blocks on the cities allow the producers to reduce the size of the cities without making them look small and have a "wall of buildings" around it. You can see there is "more city", making the game look more realistic.

Comment: Okay, fair point about making cities look bigger, though I have to say the floating sings kind of ruin the illusion. I can also see the blocked off rural roads as adding detail to the countryside. But what about the stub intersections (see screenshots #2)?

Comment: That is just to avoid you getting there by mistake, because it leads to nowhere.
They could just not make the highway exits, but I believe it's useful to spawn cars and trucks in and out of the highway.

Comment: Also that eases up the development and the process of adding a new DLC that unlocks the new areas.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect that these are areas where they planned to have roads, but didn't manage to finish placing them before releasing the game.

Personally I think more realistic "solid" roadworks would be a much more aesthetically pleasing way to block unfinished roads than the floating see-through ones that are in the game at the moment.

Answer (score -4):

I'm pretty sure they're there because you're in the demo mode. Do you have the full version or demo mode? This happens to me, too.

Comment: That is not Demo mode! read Edu answer.

Comment: Do you have the Going East DLC? @AmirrezaNasiri Well if they had unfinished roads, then why would they be there? But who even cares, this game was released over a year ago!

Comment: They are not "Unfinished roads". they are there because this is Truck game and you don't need to go into the main cities, so the cities are blocked (They are not exist, they are only some objects and textures).

Comment: I have the full version, as well as the Going East DLC (although the question was posted before said DLC was released).